# How do I select just the letters from a string of data in a column and not other characters in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a column of data in an sqlite table that has mostly strings of letters in it, but some fields contain a string of letters with numbers and other symbols such as ? or # or / .  How do I select only the letters without leaving a space, I need it to be one continuous string of letters once the letters are selected with no spaces.

For example "asdf3#?#"  needs to become "asdf"   and "ad4?erln" needs to become "aderln". The strings of data are not of fixed length and can be up to 15 or more characters long.

Comment: You could use `replace`, but that gets tedious if there are many unwanted characters. Do you really need to do this in SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use replace, I have to retain the original data as it has important notations with it (the characters I want to filter out are notes).  I need to select out all but the notation, compare it against another table and then attach the original data with the result.  Annoying to say the least.

Comment: Ok I found a work around, I have duplicated the table, replaced the notes with search and replace in text wrangler.  Now I can do my search on the modified table and then do an outer join to retrieve the data with notes from the original table... tedious but shouldn't take too long.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: The [replace function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) does not modify any table.